# comparing python dictionaries having 1 key holding more than 1 value

Tags: python-3.x

there are 3 dictionaries. i want to compare the "criteria" to "rules", if any match occurs, add it into "mydict".

```
criteria = {
    'no_of_EG': 2, 
    'no_of_VG': 2, 
    'no_of_G': 1, 
    'no_of_SG': 0, 
    'no_of_A': 0, 
    'no_of_SP': 0, 
    'no_of_P': 0, 
    'no_of_VP': 0, 
    'no_of_EP': 1}  
rules = {
    'no_of_EG' : (6,5,4,3),
    'no_of_EP' : (3,2,1),
    'no_of_VG' : (6,5,4,3),
    'no_of_G' : (6,5,4,3,2,1),
    'no_of_SG' : (6,5),
    'no_of_A' : (6,),
    'no_of_SP' : (3,2,1)}  
mydict = {
    'no_of_EG' : 0,
    'no_of_VG' : 0,
    'no_of_G' : 0,
    'no_of_SG' : 0,
    'no_of_A' : 0,
    'no_of_SP' : 0,
    'no_of_P' : 0,
    'no_of_VP' : 0,
    'no_of_EP' : 0}

mydict = {k: criteria[k] for k in criteria if k in rules and criteria[k] == rules[k]}
print("SELECTED RULES ARE:",mydict)
```

How could i update the above statement. As it only works with keys holding single values in "rules". But here in "rules", I have keys holding more than 1 value.

expected output:

```
mydict = {
    'no_of_EG' : 0,
    'no_of_VG' : 0,
    'no_of_G' : 1,
    'no_of_SG' : 0,
    'no_of_A' : 0,
    'no_of_SP' : 0,
    'no_of_P' : 0,
    'no_of_VP' : 0,
    'no_of_EP' : 1}
```

Comment: ` i want to compare the "criteria" to "rules", if any match occurs, add it into "mydict".` How do you define `match` ?

Comment: Then the values in mydict should be a list of the `values` you want it to hold

Comment: "match" means similarity. i want to hold the "key and value" in mydict as described in expected output.  not only "values"

Comment: mydict will get updated only at 'no_of_G' : 1 and no_of_EP : 1. all other values will remain 0. because there are exactly two matches (alike entries in criteria and rules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I think you want `in` instead of `==`.
2) If you want to update values than you need to call `.update(...)` not assign a new `dict`.

```
mydict.update({k: criteria[k] for k in criteria if k in rules and criteria[k] in rules[k]})
```

Also your `rules` should be `sets` not `tuples` if you have control over that.